# Fullpage.js not working on Mozilla but functioning perfectly on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

Here's the website: carrotcrunchpvp.comule.com. The website is made for 16 : 9 but thats besides the point - It doesnt seem to want to go to any of the navigation links, you cant touch scroll and you cant used the keyboard (most importantly...). I've tried changing the version of jquery around to an older version but it doesn't fix anything.

I'm getting this popping up in the console when I click a direction (for e.g):
KeyboardEvent.key value "Left" is obsolete and will be renamed to "ArrowLeft". For more help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent.key

and

Calctheta is not define which is part of the intialisation.js http://carrotcrunchpvp.comule.com/intialisation.js

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in Chrome either...
You can not initialise the plugin before including it. You are including your file `initialisation.js` before than `fullPage.js`.

This is not exclusive of fullpage.js, this is like so for any other plugin or javascript function.

The initialization inclusion should be at the end, just after any plugin being initialized there.

```
<title>Catholic Professional Standards</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="jquery.fullPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="media_queries.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="jquery.fullPage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="loadingscreen.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="intialisation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine on Chrome, however the problem lies that none of the navigation works at all on firefox or chrome

Comment: @ChrisConnolly as the creator of fullPage.js I'm telling you that **you should** do what I told you. Is up to you if you want to fix it or not. If you still having problems after it, come back again.

Comment: As a end user. I did. It didn't work. Check the website again, I added **your** code onto it so you can see why it wont work in FF.

Comment: @ChrisConnolly you clearly has solve one of the problems you had. You want to see it or not, the error messages have disappeared from Firefox console on page load. Now, you have another error: `ReferenceError: calcTheta is not defined  intialisation.js:147`. Take a look at it.

Comment: Are you going to help me or just point out problems which were already identified in the original question!

Comment: @ChrisConnolly I would move all the functions outside the fullPage.js initialization and leave them just inside document.ready.

Comment: They need to be within, I want those functions to only work with the event handlers you have setup like onSlideLeave etc.

Comment: @ChrisConnolly well, I'm telling what I will try in order to solve it. Feel fee to do it or not.

Comment: Touche - it worked. However I need the code for the website to work well... I don't know why it won't work with Mozilla?

Comment: The issue is definetly within this code:
http://carrotcrunchpvp.comule.com/intialisation.js

Comment: I told you to move the functions outside the callbacks... you are not coding it properly... In any case, move them AT LEAST outside the if condition. You can see a reproduction of your problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/454/). And the solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/455/). But next time, rather than just ignoring what you are told, consider asking "why" or even changing your code to adapt to the proposed solution.

Comment: I dont know how you mean, what would [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yhtbasmf/) change to? Ive tried to shimmy the functions outside the callbacks but it doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: I said you should move them outside the condition they are in. Place them just in the 1st line of the callback.

Comment: Awesome it fixed it! Cheers Alvaro!

Comment: @ChrisConnolly yeah, its said in the docs. And don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Hmm.... I'm back to square one with Safari and I.E... Same idea. Nav doesn't work etc etc.

Comment: @ChrisConnolly you should open a new question for that. I've treated the problem for this one and solved it. Now it's working in Mozilla.